# vue.jsのJSON.parseで\x22をパースできない。

Tags: javascript, vue.js

vue.jsを使ってhtmlのデータ属性のjsonを読み込もうとしているのですが、データ属性の値を取ってきて`JSON.parse`を適用すると以下のエラーが出ます。

```
Unexpected token \ in JSON at position 1
```

**index.html**

```
<div id="app" data-servers="{\x22name\x22: \x22aaa\x22}">
    {{ servers }}
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: () => {
        const servers = document.getElementById('app').dataset.servers;
        console.log(servers);
        return {
            servers: JSON.parse(servers)
        }
    }
})
```

普通のJavaScriptではJSON.parseでエスケープ済みの文字列をパースできましたがvue.js上では動きません。

vue.jsでhtml上のjsonをパースするにはどのようにすればよいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML属性はJavaScriptではありませんから、`\x22`と言うのはエスケープでもなんでもなく、そのまま4つの文字`\` `x` `2` `2`を表すだけになります。

例えば以下のようにしてみてください。

```
<div id="app" data-servers="{&#34;name&#34;: &#34;aaa&#34;}">
```

あるいは、

```
<div id="app" data-servers='{"name": "aaa"}'>
```

Comment: 無理矢理やるならば、 `servers.replace(/\\x22/g, '\x22')` でも良いですね。